# NoSuchFieldException forceHeavyWeightPopupKey when running the jar file

Tags: java, swing

I am using netbeans for my project when am running the project from netbeans every thing is working fine.but I am getting NoSuchFieldException forceHeavyWeightPopupKey when running the project by double clicking the build jar file.

I think i should mention one more thing that if the jar file is run from cmd forceHeavyWeightPopupKey is working as expected.

i am using the forceHeavyWeightPopupKey for a JComboBox.. this is the code I found on the web

```
try {                   
Class cls = Class.forName("javax.swing.PopupFactory");
    javax.swing.PopupFactory ob=new javax.swing.PopupFactory();
Field field = cls.getDeclaredField("forceHeavyWeightPopupKey");
field.setAccessible(true);
    combo.putClientProperty(field.get(""), Boolean.TRUE);
    //combo.putClientProperty(new StringBuffer("_force_heavy_weight_popup_"), Boolean.TRUE);
} catch (Exception e1) {add(new JLabel(e1.toString()));

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to `forceHeavyWeightPopupKey`? If it's private there's usually a good reason for it.

Comment: Do you have multiple JDKs on your computer? Double-clicking the JAR might run it in JDK 1.7 where `PopupFactory.forceHeavyWeightPopupKey` seems to have moved to `ClientPropertyKey.PopupFactory_FORCE_HEAVYWEIGHT_POPUP`.

Comment: Also, don't pass the empty string `""` to `Field.get()` (no `String` instance will have a field called `forceHeavyWeightPopupKey`), pass in `null` which tells `get()` you're looking for a static field (which `PopupFactory.forceHeavyWeightPopupKey` is).

Comment: I have already used null in place of empty string but that did't work too.is there any alternative?